# I don't understand the behavior of this C code (union with 2 bit-field structs, a word and a byte array)

Tags: c, struct, unions, bit-fields

I have the following piece of code in C:

```
typedef union _REG_CiFIFOCON {
    struct {
        uint32_t RxNotEmptyIE : 1;
        uint32_t RxHalfFullIE : 1;
        uint32_t RxFullIE : 1;
        uint32_t RxOverFlowIE : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented1 : 1;
        uint32_t RxTimeStampEnable : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented2 : 1;
        uint32_t TxEnable : 1;
        uint32_t UINC : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented3 : 1;
        uint32_t FRESET : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented4 : 13;
        uint32_t FifoSize : 5;
        uint32_t PayLoadSize : 3;
    } rxBF;

    struct {
        uint32_t TxNotFullIE : 1;
        uint32_t TxHalfFullIE : 1;
        uint32_t TxEmptyIE : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented1 : 1;
        uint32_t TxAttemptIE : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented2 : 1;
        uint32_t RTREnable : 1;
        uint32_t TxEnable : 1;
        uint32_t UINC : 1;
        uint32_t TxRequest : 1;
        uint32_t FRESET : 1;
        uint32_t unimplemented3 : 5;
        uint32_t TxPriority : 5;
        uint32_t TxAttempts : 2;
        uint32_t unimplemented4 : 1;
        uint32_t FifoSize : 5;
        uint32_t PayLoadSize : 3;
    } txBF;
    uint32_t word;
    uint8_t byte[4];
} REG_CiFIFOCON;
```

Both structs are 32 bit, so it is the word variable and the byte array (as this is composed of 4 bytes. 4x8 = 32 bits).

My problem is: I don't understand the behavior of this union. I know how to access the bits in each struct and both the word and the array, but how are they related? I know that if there was only 1 struct and the word, setting the word to some value would modify accordingly the bit fields (and viceversa), but I don't know what happens in this case.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: They all occupy the exact same place in memory - that's what the `union` definition means. It doesn't matter how many different types there are in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 types in the same union. All of them are using the same memory.

It doesn't matter which one of them you change - it will affect the others.

The size of your type is 32 bytes - which in your case is also the size of every type inside it. Otherwise - it will be the size of the largest type inside.

Comment: So the variable word, the byte array, and both structs will have always the same values? So if one is modified, the other three will also be modified accordingly?